# AngularJS prepending my select box with an option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**AngularJS**

```
app.factory('SnazzyService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        getList: function(){
            return $http.get('feed.php');
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('MenuSideController', ['$scope','SnazzyService','$modal','$log', function($scope, SnazzyService, $modal, $log) {

        SnazzyService.getList().success(function(snazzy){
            $scope.snazzy = snazzy;
        });
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<select data-ng-model="user.snazzy" data-ng-options="a.name for a in snazzy">                
</select>
```

I have the above code which works fine and outputs my select box with options. My question is, how do I prepend the Select box options with a value such as `<option value="NONE" selected="selected">None</option>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect):

> Optionally, a single hard-coded `<option>` element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the `<select>` element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.

Example:

```
    <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
      <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if OP wanted to style just this one or all of them. I guess he can combine our two answers.

Comment: This works thanks! Throws an error when I use ng-change as it compares data from the json supplied to make the list

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear if you want to append a single option to your select or you wish to modify all of them. If it's the latter, you can always use ng-repeat on the option element like this:

```
<select data-ng-model="snazzy">
      <option ng-repeat="s in snazzy" value="NONE" selected="selected">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
```